# How does an Oracle table know which sequence it is associated with?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, sequence, sequences

I want to know how an Oracle table (or column) knows which sequence is used or applies to that specific table (or column).

Comment: Prior to 12c, sequences are not associated to tables, so the table does not know which sequence to use. 12c introduces options for using sequences in identity columns and default constraints. That information should be available in the data dictionary.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: I'm pretty out of date with Oracle. Happen to have a link to how that works?

Comment: @JonEricson https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAECCFH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, sequences *aren't* systematically associated with a particular table in Oracle. According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11793):

> Without sequences, sequential values can only be produced programmatically. A new primary key value can be obtained by selecting the most recently produced value and incrementing it. This method requires a lock during the transaction and causes multiple users to wait for the next value of the primary key; this waiting is known as **serialization**. If developers have such constructs in applications, then you should encourage the developers to replace them with access to sequences. Sequences eliminate serialization and improve the concurrency of an application.

So the developers of the application need to associate each sequence with the table(s) they are used with. Usually this is done by using a name that somehow indicates what it's used for. So a sequence for populating `emp` table's primary key might be called `emp_sequence`.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 12c you can create a column with an identity clause.

```
create table MY_TABLE(
    ID number generated always as identity
)
/
```

This creates a sequence that is associated with that column. You can query the view [ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS.htm#REFRN20830) to find out the system generated name of the sequence:

```
select owner, sequence_name
from ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS
where owner='MY_SCHEMA'
and table_name='MY_TABLE'
and column_name='MY_COLUMN'
/
```